# Changing SSH port with a bash script on CentOS

Tags: bash, ssh, port, centos6

SO I wrote a script that can change the SSH port on CentOS but for some reason I'm encountering this error:

> sshchangecOS6.sh: line 36: syntax error: unexpected end of file

This is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
# This script changes the ssh port for logins on CentOS 5 and 6
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
echo "This script must be run as root"
   exit 2
read -r -p "Would you like to change the ssh port? [Y/N] " response
if [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
then    
   read -p "What would you like to change the port to? (Chose between 1024-65535) " sshportconfig
   if (( ("$sshportconfig" > 1024) && ("$sshportconfig" < 65535) )); then
    echo "Port $sshportconfig" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo "SSH port has been changed to: $sshportconfig. Written by Sincere the Minotaur."
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
   else
    echo "Port chosen is incorrect."
    exit 1
   fi
else 
   sshPort=$(grep "Port" /etc/ssh/sshd_config) | head -n 1
   echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
   echo ""
   echo ""
   echo "SSH is still: $sshPort"
   echo "Written by Sincere the Minotaur."
   echo ""
   echo "---------------------------------------------------------------------"
   exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Could someone explain where the errors are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `fi` for the first if `if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then`. You need to close every `if` with a `fi`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something.